# (VC++) Runtime Check for Uninitialized Variables: How is the test Implemented?

Tags: visual-c++, assembly, compiler-construction, x86

I'm trying to understand what this test does exactly.  This toy code

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int i;
    printf("%d", i);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiles into this:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
```

{
012C2DF0  push        ebp
012C2DF1  mov         ebp,esp
012C2DF3  sub         esp,0D8h
012C2DF9  push        ebx
012C2DFA  push        esi
012C2DFB  push        edi
012C2DFC  lea         edi,[ebp-0D8h]
012C2E02  mov         ecx,36h
012C2E07  mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh
012C2E0C  rep stos    dword ptr es:[edi]
**012C2E0E  mov         byte ptr [ebp-0D1h],0**

```
int i;
printf("%d", i);
```

**012C2E15  cmp         byte ptr [ebp-0D1h],0

012C2E1C  jne         wmain+3Bh (012C2E2Bh)

012C2E1E  push        12C2E5Ch

012C2E23  call        __RTC_UninitUse (012C10B9h)**
012C2E28  add         esp,4
012C2E2B  mov         esi,esp
012C2E2D  mov         eax,dword ptr [i]
012C2E30  push        eax
012C2E31  push        12C5858h
012C2E36  call        dword ptr ds:[12C9114h]
012C2E3C  add         esp,8
012C2E3F  cmp         esi,esp
012C2E41  call        __RTC_CheckEsp (012C1140h)

```
return 0;
```

012C2E46  xor         eax,eax
}
012C2E48  pop         edi
012C2E49  pop         esi
012C2E4A  pop         ebx
012C2E4B  add         esp,0D8h
012C2E51  cmp         ebp,esp
012C2E53  call        __RTC_CheckEsp (012C1140h)
012C2E58  mov         esp,ebp
012C2E5A  pop         ebp
012C2E5B  ret

The 5 lines emphasized are the only ones removed by properly initializing the variable i. The lines 'push 12C2E5Ch,  call __RTC_UninitUse'  call the function that display the error box, with a pointer to a string containing the variable name ("i") as an argument.

What I can't understand are the 3 lines that perform the actual test:

012C2E0E  mov         byte ptr [ebp-0D1h],0
012C2E15  cmp         byte ptr [ebp-0D1h],0
012C2E1C  jne         wmain+3Bh (012C2E2Bh)

It would have seemed the compiler is probing the stack area of i (setting a byte to zero and immediately testing whether it's zero), just to be sure it isn't initialized somewhere it couldn't see during build.  However, the probed address, ebp-0D1h,  has little to do with the actual address of i.

Even worse, it seems if there were such an external (other thread?) initialization that did initialize the probed address but *to zero*, this test would still shout about the variable being uninitialized.

What's going on? Maybe the probe is meant for something entirely different, say to test if a certain byte is writable?

Comment: The code itself is zeroing the location it tests, so the branch should never be taken and thus the message printed. It doesn't make much sense to me, unless this was compiled without optimization.

Comment: /RTC lives only in unoptimized builds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my guess: the compiler probably allocates flags in memory showing the initialization status of variables. In your case for variable `i` this is a single byte at `[ebp-0D1h]`. The zeroing of this byte means `i` is not initialized. I assume if you initialize `i` this byte will be set to non-zero. Try something run-time like this: `if (argc > 1) i = 1;` This should generate code instead of omitting the whole check. You can also add another variable, and see if you get two different flags.

The zeroing of the flag and the testing just happen to be consecutive in this case, but that might not always be the case.

Comment: Yes!    I tried to verify this previously with different code and couldn't.   Even adding 'void dummy(const int& arg)  { printf("42"); }' and calling 'dummy(i);'  removed the test code.  But branching on argc as you suggested does separate the store of the flag from its test.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

`[ebp-0D1h]` is a temporary variable used by the compiler to track "initialized" status of variables. If we modify the source a bit, it will be more clear:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int i, j;
    printf("%d %d", i, j);
    i = 1;
    printf("%d %d", i, j);
    j = 2;
    return 0;
}
```

Produces the following (irrelevant parts skipped):

```
mov DWORD PTR [ebp-12], -858993460      ; ccccccccH
mov DWORD PTR [ebp-8], -858993460       ; ccccccccH
mov DWORD PTR [ebp-4], -858993460       ; ccccccccH
mov BYTE PTR $T4694[ebp], 0
mov BYTE PTR $T4693[ebp], 0
```

In prolog, variables are filled with 0xCC, and two tracking variables (one for `i` and one for `j`) are set to 0.

```
; 7    :        printf("%d %d", i, j);    
    cmp BYTE PTR $T4693[ebp], 0
    jne SHORT $LN3@main
    push    OFFSET $LN4@main
    call    __RTC_UninitUse
    add esp, 4
$LN3@main:
    cmp BYTE PTR $T4694[ebp], 0
    jne SHORT $LN5@main
    push    OFFSET $LN6@main
    call    __RTC_UninitUse
    add esp, 4
$LN5@main:
    mov eax, DWORD PTR _j$[ebp]
    push    eax
    mov ecx, DWORD PTR _i$[ebp]
    push    ecx
    push    OFFSET $SG4678
    call    _printf
    add esp, 12                 ; 0000000cH
```

This corresponds roughly to:

```
if ( $T4693 == 0 )
  _RTC_UninitUse("j");
if ( $T4694 == 0 )
  _RTC_UninitUse("j");
printf("%d %d", i, j);
```

Next part:

```
; 8    :        i = 1;    
    mov BYTE PTR $T4694[ebp], 1
    mov DWORD PTR _i$[ebp], 1
```

So, once `i` is intialized, the tracking variable is set to 1.

```
; 10   :        j = 2;
mov BYTE PTR $T4693[ebp], 1
mov DWORD PTR _j$[ebp], 2
```

Here, the same is happening for `j`.

Answer (score -1):

```
C7060F000055    mov     dword ptr [esi],5500000Fh
C746048BEC5151  mov     dword ptr [esi+0004],5151EC8Bh
```

b. And one of its later generations:

```
BF0F000055  mov     edi,5500000Fh
893E    mov     [esi],edi
5F  pop     edi
52  push    edx
B640    mov     dh,40
BA8BEC5151  mov     edx,5151EC8Bh
53  push    ebx
8BDA    mov     ebx,edx
895E04  mov     [esi+0004],ebx
```

c. And yet another generation with recalculated ("encrypted") "constant" data:

```
BB0F000055  mov     ebx,5500000Fh
891E    mov     [esi],ebx
5B  pop     ebx
51  push    ecx
B9CB00C05F  mov     ecx,5FC000CBh
81C1C0EB91F1    add     ecx,F191EBC0h ; ecx=5151EC8Bh
```

Comment: What is the point of this answer?  That code doesn't appear in the question.  And it seems nonsensical, e.g. `mov dh, 40` right before overwriting the whole EDX with a mov-immediate.  And `pop` / `push` replaces the bottom DWORD on the stack with some previously-untouched register, but why would you want that?  This certainly doesn't look like an answer to the question about how MSVC's compiler-generated debug-mode asm works.